# How to make the content in body viewable with anchor fixed bottom div there?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code:

```js
$('body').append('<section id="test" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;margin:0 auto;text-align: center;width: 100%;"><div style="width:100%;height:250px;background:#f00;margin: 0 auto;">some fixed text</div></section>');

for (var i = 0; i<Math.random()*5000; i++) {
  $('#content').append('<li>test node (need to be displayed)</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="content"></ul>
```

My problem is if there are many contents that makes the screen needs to scroll, the fixed div will block the content. How do I make sure that all the contents are displaying? I can add `body{margin-bottom:1000px;}` but how can I make that value adjusted according to the real height of its content, rather than a fixed `1000px`?

Comment: Why not post the actual question that's in your code, to your post?

Comment:  Sorry you must written and question for help you ... Thanks !!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are having a better reputation and in SO you have asked too many questions so far, you should have known [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As height of your fixed div is `250px`, simply give your `body` a `margin-bottom` of any value greater than `250px` that is suitable for you. In `jQuery`, you have to write in this way:

```
$('body').css('margin-bottom','260px');
```

So, the complete code goes like this:

```js
$('body').append('<section id="test" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;margin:0 auto;text-align: center;width: 100%;"><div style="width:100%;height:250px;background:#f00;margin: 0 auto;">some fixed text</div></section>');

$('body').css('margin-bottom','260px');

for (var i = 0; i<Math.random()*5000; i++) {
  $('#content').append('<li>test node (need to be displayed)</li>');
}

$('#content').append('<li>THIS IS THE LAST NODE</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="content"></ul>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3s19Lkry/24/

Comment: Thanks. What if the `#content` is not some fixed element, but a changeable element? I would like to make the CSS unrelated to the content elements, but applied to the `body` (like `body{padding:160px}`). Is that possible?

Comment: @AGamePlayer Well, that is possible, too. But not the `padding`...you have to change the `margin` , more precisely `margin-bottom`. I've updated my answer. May be, this solves your issue.